# Dagger gives Cyclic dependency when using recommended architecture

Tags: android, dagger-2, androidx, android-jetpack, cyclic-dependency

I want to build an android app using the [suggested architecture here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide). However after following the guide and using dagger for all my classes I ended up with a cyclic dependency summarised as

android.app.Application <- (Retrofit) ServerClient <- UserRepository <- UserViewModel <- UserActivity <- somethingsomething <- android.app.Application

The more detailed version is here:

```
android-client/app/src/main/java/de/njsm/stocks/android/dagger/RootComponent.java:22: error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
public interface RootComponent extends AndroidInjector<Application> {
       ^

      android.app.Application is injected at
          de.njsm.stocks.android.dagger.modules.WebModule.fdsa(a)
      android.app.Application is injected at
          de.njsm.stocks.android.dagger.modules.WebModule.provideServerClient(ctx)
      de.njsm.stocks.android.network.server.ServerClient is injected at
          de.njsm.stocks.android.repo.UserRepository(…, webclient, …)
      de.njsm.stocks.android.repo.UserRepository is injected at
          de.njsm.stocks.android.dagger.modules.ViewModelModule.provideUserViewModel(repo)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          de.njsm.stocks.android.dagger.modules.ViewModelModule.viewModelFactory(providerMap)
      androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
          de.njsm.stocks.android.frontend.user.UserActivity.setViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory)
      de.njsm.stocks.android.frontend.user.UserActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [de.njsm.stocks.android.dagger.RootComponent → de.njsm.stocks.android.dagger.modules.ActivityModule_ContributeUserActivity.UserActivitySubcomponent]
```

I understand why the problem is there. My dependencies follow the direction backend to frontend and at the "leaf" in the backend I need an android context to get access to the filesystem to load the keystore and Room DB. What I'm wondering is: As I simply follow the architecture layout I cannot be the first one to run into this. How can I break this cycle? My favourite cut would betweeen the activity and the application because AFAIU an application can exist without an activity in android.

To inject the activities I followed the [dagger guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/android) and the rest is simple (and working) dagger config.